# Does boiling chia seed affect the amount of omega 3 (ALA) in them?

Tags: boiling, nutrient-composition, chia

I used to add them to lentils in a stew like dish, mainly to get my ALA requirements. I read that Omega 3 fatty acids are not heat stable but I am not sure at what temperature they are broken down.

Comment: To the close voter: This is exactly the kind of nutrition question that is on topic: It’s measurable, answerable with facts and limited in scope

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [on the Medical Science Exchange](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/when-boiling-steaming-spinach-or-kale-are-the-omega-3-oils-boiled-out). In short: boiling/steaming is around 100 °C, simmering even lower. Boiling point of ALA is 230 °C, so it should not be boiled out. The other concern, oxidation, also only sets in at 120 °C. If you're not using a pressure cooker, you will not hit 120 °C and the ALA should be almost completely preserved, as far as the science goes.